# Saving Pytorch model error: codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have seen similar questions regarding the loading of a pytorch model, but not the saving of one and the solutions offered on those questions have not solved my problem.

Here is the code I have to save the model:

```
PATH = "c:\Users\my_name\Desktop\model"
torch.save(model, PATH)
```

But I am stuck getting the title error. I am saving the model without a checkpoint, before evaluating. Not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path is just my c: drive, for whatever reason the error is fixed. Still unsure about why I cant select a deeper path.

Answer (score 0):

It's a better practice to only save the `state_dict`.

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

and load the checkpoint:

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, either practice results in this error.